# Sliding (on hover) search box on touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, slide, jquery-slide-effects

I have a search button. When you hover it textarea slides to the left. If you click it, it searches the term. Anyway, how can I optimize it for touch devices?

I tried making it slide on first touch and search in second touch but I wasn't able to do it.

```
<input type="text" onBlur="if (this.value == '')
this.value = this.defaultValue;" onFocus="if (this.value == this.defaultValue)
this.value = '';" value="Arama" name="s" class="search-text">
<input type="submit" value="" name="submit" class="search-submit">
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/Direnk/Z9gXS/2/)

If you can help me, that would be great! Best.

Comment: With touch device optimized pages you don't really want to put any action behind a "hover" because it's not intuitive to hold your finger over that point and you would have to quickly let go and click the input box (in your case). I would start with designing this a different way.

Comment: Your idea of making it slide on first touch then submit on the second one is great! What didn't work exactly? That's the code you should put here!